# Add controller path/function to button

Tags: magento2

I have a button in a dynamic setting array like this

```
$this->addColumn(
    'col_2',
    [
        'label' => __('download'), 
         'renderer'  => $this->getInsta(),
    ]
);
```

How can I call the function from the controller by clicking this button in admin panel ??

[image]

I want add controller function to butto edit in action

Comment: can you share screenshot of what you're expecting to do?

Comment: ok i shared, update question

Comment: where is your button?

Comment: Admin panel ->stores ->  Configuration -> catalog -> Catalog -> i have my custom tab

Answer (score 0):

Try by this way:

```
$link= $this->getUrl('module/controller/method');
$this->addColumn(
    'action',
    array(
    'header'   => __('Actions'),
    'sortable' => false,
    'filter'   => false,
    'type'     => 'action',
    'actions'  => array(
        array(
            'url'     => $link,
            'caption' => __('Terminate Session'),
            'confirm' => __('Are you sure?'),
        ),
    ),
    )
);
```

Comment: no generate buton